# How to change color by clicking cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tables like below.

I would like to change colors by clicking and mounsedown and mouseovering on it. I realize such coloring,but I would like to show color transition.

For example,my desired result is when first clicked,td's color will be changed to green and 
then,when we clicked greened cells,the color will be changed to Yellow.

How can I realize this color transition?

If you have already experienced,please let me know.

[image]

```
$(function () {
      var first;
      var second;
      $("#table td")
        .mousedown(function () {
          first = this.id;
          console.log("first",first);
          return false; // prevent text selection
        });

      $("#table td")
        .mouseup(function () {
          second = this.id;
          console.log("second",second);

          if(first==second){
            changecolor(first,"0f0");
          }
          else if(first<second){
              for (var i=first;i<=second; i++)
                changecolor(i,"aqua");
              }
          else{
              for (var i=second;i<=first; i++)
                changecolor(i,"aqua");}            
          return false;
        });
    });

      function changecolor(id,color){
  $("#"+id).css("background-color",color);}
```

Comment: Why not use `$(this)`, instead of all that insanity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here are two possible versions you can try.

Long version:

```
$(function () {
    $("td").mousedown(function () {
        const green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)"
        const yellow = "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
        if ($(this).css('background-color') == green )
            changecolor(this, yellow)
        else
            changecolor(this, green)
        return false
    });
});

function changecolor(el, color) {
    $(el).css("background-color", color);
}
```

Short version:

```
$(function(){
  $("td").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color',
        $(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(0, 128, 0)" ?
            "rgb(255, 255, 0)" : "rgb(0, 128, 0)")
    return false
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        .green{
            background-color:green;
        }
        .yellow{
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>age</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="">john</td>
                            <td class="">23</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="">tony</td>
                            <td class="">26</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tbody td").click(function(){
                let className = $(this).attr('class')
                if(className == ''){
                    $(this).addClass('green')
                }
                else if(className == "green"){
                    $(this).removeClass('green')
                    $(this).addClass('yellow')
                }
                else{
                    console.log("do something")
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

try it